# How do you perform an AJAX submit and do a get in backbone.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm trying to pull data via a AJAX submit and render it into a div `#search_results` in backbone.  How do I do this?  I am entirely new to backbone and still learning.

Thanks!

RoR Controller:

```
class ClassroomsController < PublicController
  def search
    @search_result = Classroom.first
    respond_with @search_result
  end
end
```

RoR View:

```
= form_tag search_path, :method => :get, :id => "search_form", do
  = text_field_tag :search_textbox
  = submit_tag "Search", :id => "search_button"
#search_results
```

classrooms/search.js.erb:

```
$("#search_results").html("<%=escape_javascript(render 'search')%>");
```

classrooms/search.html.haml:

```
= @search_result.classroom.title
```

backbone.js View:

```
class Classrooms.Views.Classroom extends Backbone.View

  events:
    "submit #search_button": "getResults"

  render: ->
    $(@el).html($("#classroom_main").html())
    @setActiveNavItem("main")
    this

  getResults: (event) ->
    event.stopPropagation()
    event.preventDefault()
    $.get $(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), null, "script"
    return false
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi BackboneJS works a litte different,
it has MVC in client and a RESTful backend.

http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-use-Backbone-js-with-Ajax-calls-to-the-server/answer/Diego-Castorina

maybe this links help you to understand MVC, REST and Backbone:

- http://backbonetutorials.com/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-started-with-backbone-js/
- https://github.com/kjbekkelund/writings/blob/master/published/understanding-backbone.md/

Good Luck